# text editor loading multiple large text files - multi threaded

Tags: vb.net, winforms, multithreading

I'm fairly new to VB.NET, and I'm working on a text editor with a tabbed interface. I deal with large text files, so I'm wondering what is the best way to go about this.

Should I have each tab / text document open up in a new thread or a process? I basically want the entire application to always run fast as the text editor is just one part of it. If I have several large text files open I don't want the rest of the application slowing down a bit.

If someone can help shed light on this and maybe point me to a URL with any relevant examples, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Should I have each tab / text document open up in a new thread or a process?**

No. Definitely not a new process. The amount of Win32 to put everything back together will make you hate yourself.

Not a new thread either. The Winforms UI runs in a *single* dispatch thread. Trying to touch the UI from different threads will make your program explode.

I would recommend simply using the tried, true, and boring *background worker* approach. This can be used with threads or just using *asynchronous IO* (.NET handles the threading for you). Depending upon your use case you may want to just lazy-load parts of files, you can use *memory mapped* or *random access* files (e.g. only read in a very small part of the file at a time). In any case the "data" should be separate from the visualization of said data.

(Emphasis added to search terms.)

Answer (score 1):

Whether you have 1 or 10 tabs open, you will only be able to type/edit 1 file at a time, the other tabs will just be taking up memory in the data structure you define, so not sure how there would be an impact on performance.

As a side note, if you are doing a large amount of string manipulation use the stringbuilder class, far quicker and memory efficient.